# Passing values to an function

Tags: c, arrays, parameters, parameter-passing

I am missing a fundamental point on passing values.

In my code, I wrote this prototype/function:

```
void drawFont (char A[],unsigned char length, char x1, char y1, uint16 FGcolor);
```

I call the function using a call like this:

```
drawFont ("William",7,15,25,YEL,0);
```

or

```
drawFont ("W",1,15,25,YEL,0);
```

Both of these work fine in the code.  If I examine A[0] in the function, I will see a value of '57' representing an ASCII 'W'.  All fine and good.

My question/problem is:  When I attempt to replicate the 'W' using the ASCII value instead of the string representation, my code fails  Example:

```
drawFont (57,1,15,25,YEL,0);
```

The value of A[0] in the code is: 0, but the address of A is 57.  So somehow the compiler assumes that I want to pass a pointer?  I'm confused, why did it pass the string fine, but not the value?

Thanks in advance from a novice C programmer.

Comment: "somehow the compiler assumes that I want to pass a pointer" - that is *exactly* what `char A[]` is in the context of that parameter list. A debugger and/or `printf("%p : %s", A, A);` at the top of `drawFont` for your first two examples will likely be something you find interesting.

Comment: Not really.  Im using a debugger, that is how I know what is happening.  I really wish printf was available to me!  That would soooo simplify things.  But this is a microcontroller, so most of my questions are theoretical, as output is difficult to test.  I usually have to examine values and ask,"Why?".

Comment: the prototype shows 5 parameters however, each of the invocations shows 6 parameters.  The compiler should have issued a (at least) warning message. for each of the invocations.  did you use a parameter on the compile something like (for GCC compiler) -Wall?

Comment: Good eye, but off topic.  I shorten the parameter list so you didn't have to scroll to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype for your function declares that the first parameter is a pointer to a character:

```
void drawFont (char A[],...);
```

If you pass an integer, you are breaking the rules.  The compiler should warn about it.  Mine gives a warning about the following code on the line with `func(57)`:

```c
void func(char a[])
{
}

char arr[] = {87,84,70};

int main()
{
    func(57);
    func("W");
    func(arr);
}
```

```
x.c(9) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
x.c(9) : warning C4024: 'func' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
```

If you look at the assembly output from the compiler, you can see the problem more clearly (I cut out the uninteresting parts):

```asm
PUBLIC  _arr
_DATA   SEGMENT
_arr    DB      057H                ;Here's the char array at an address in memory.
        DB      054H
        DB      046H
        ORG $+1
$SG1297 DB      'W', 00H   ;Here's the "W" at an address in memory (nul-terminated)
_DATA   ENDS

; 9    :     func(57);

  00003 6a 39            push    57                  ; Push 57 as the address, WRONG!
  00005 e8 00 00 00 00   call    _func
  0000a 83 c4 04         add     esp, 4

; 10   :     func("W");

  0000d 68 00 00 00 00   push    OFFSET $SG1297      ; Push the address of the string.
  00012 e8 00 00 00 00   call    _func
  00017 83 c4 04         add     esp, 4

; 11   :     func(arr);

  0001a 68 00 00 00 00   push    OFFSET _arr         ; Push the address of the array.
  0001f e8 00 00 00 00   call    _func
  00024 83 c4 04         add     esp, 4
```

The code is expecting to go to an address to read characters.  Who knows what is in address 57.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Your function array parameter is declared as indirect, I don't know if that is why your compiler is complaining.  Mine does not give a warning, nor is it declared as such.  Further, a char is a 8bit number/ a small integer so to speak, the compiler wont care how you are using it.  My problem specifically is why the "W" gets pushed into the char array as 57, but the literal 57 ends up as an address/pointer.  So phrased another way, if I wanted to push a slew of literals into that array how would I do that?

Comment: There is no difference between declaring `char* a` and `char a[]`.  It generates the exact same code and even the exact same error (including the `char *` in the message.  I'll update it to match your declaration, but they are two ways to declare that a `char` _pointer_ is expected.

Comment: You cannot pass a `57` to a function expecting a pointer without problems.  That your compiler doesn't even warn you about the problem is unfortunate.  Perhaps check that you can increase the warning level with a command line parameter?

Comment: Pass an actual array of characters not a single number.  The function expects an address.  I'll update my example with another version of the call.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass

```
drawFont (57,1,15,25,YEL,0);
```

you will be doming the same as

```
drawFont ('W',1,15,25,YEL,0);
```

which is just one character. The function requires an array of characters, that's why it's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The *value* of `A[]` is actually a pointer, such as `&A[0]` (you could rewrite the function using `char *A` instead of `char A[]`

That is the *address* of the first slot, not what is stored in it. In the memory location pointed to by the pointer, there exists a value `57`. When you write a function with a char array or char pointer parameter, you tell the compiler: I will pass you a memory address. Go to that address and start reading each char (number) until you arrive at the null byte, then stop.

But when you pass literal integer 57 as the argument, that is not a valid pointer to an array of characters. You are missing the level of indirection.

So lets assume your char A[] resides at `0xfeaa0011`

In RAM at `0xfeaa0011` -> "William" (or 52, ...)

The correct call to drawFont() actually looks like drawFont(`0xfeaa0011`, 1, 15, 25, YEL, 0)

So you see replacing the pointer with 57 isn't the same thing.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about the indirection of the pointer.  What I am still missing is; the char value being passed is a value (in the end), so how would I 'cast' the literal 57 to pass properly, or is there a operator that instructs the compiler to treat the literal (57) as a literal and not a pointer reference?

Comment: You are still not connecting something. You could store 57 somewhere in a memory address, and then pass the address of the 57 to the function. That is what an array is. It isn't about literal vs pointer, it is literally a memory address in one case vs a small integer (57) in the other. That function will think you meant address 57

Comment: The only way you can add a level of indirection to the 57 is to store it somewhere. By itself, the 57 is a literal or "immediate" value, which doesn't even allow you to take the address of it.

Comment: Solely for illustration, you could do this extremely dangerous, ugly thing:  char c = 57; char t = 0; drawFont(&c, ...);   where the t is needed to be a null "terminator" but there is no guarantee that t will follow. Otherwise, use of the array is the only right way to do it.

Comment: I am nodding and agreeing, the array is a storage mechanism.  It 'shouldn't' care if I pass a literal or a string, both are values.  I thought both would arrive in the function as the same value (57), but one does, the other arrives as an address (pointer).  So why is the literal being seen as a pointer, clearly I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Because you've declared the parameter as a pointer. The compiler doesn't care what the argument (52 or "William") is, it cares that the function signature says `drawFont(char []A, ..). So the type "context" comes from the parameter, not the argument.

Comment: When you cast something, you are only faking/forcing the compiler to reinterpret a value as another type.

Comment: When you write a function with a char array or char pointer parameter, you tell the compiler: I will pass you a memory address. Go to that address and start reading each char (number) until you arrive at the null byte, then stop.

Comment: I agree with everything you are writing, but I still don't see why when I pass the "W" the array has the address value of 0x9D002470, and when I pass the literal, the array has the address value of 0x39 (57).  I didn't tell it to treat the literal any different.  Both the literal and the string have the same value.

Comment: There is a difference in passing double quoted string "W" and single quote 'W'. "W" is actually stored as an array in the data segment of the program. It is converted to a char * (pointer).

Comment: Note that when you pass `"W"` you actually give the address of a string of **2** characters : `W` and the Null-terminating byte of the string `\0`. If you declare `char array[] = {0x39, 0x00};` and pass `array` as the 1st argument, your compiler will be happy.

Comment: Im not passing a string, so it does not contain the \0.  I did try your suggestion and added the terminator, but that changes multiple things that I am not willing to do.  To summarize the problem/misunderstanding (on my part): Why the "W" gets pushed into the char array as 57, but the literal 57 ends up as an address/pointer. So phrased another way, if I wanted to push a slew of literals into that array how would I do that?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to pass a literal as a character string? The answer to "why" is based on types. A compiler is designed to associate semantic actions and transformations to each type based on the rules of that type. So quite simply, you declare the function to receive a character array pointer. You can't then expect the compiler to treat any value differently. The rules are from the type, not the passed value. 57 is passed as a pointer because you told the compiler the parameter will be a pointer by the way you wrote the function.

Comment: So if you want to push a bunch of literal W's into an array, do arr[0] = 57; arr[1] = 57; arr[2] = 57; ... and so forth. Or make an inline array `char arr[] = {'W', 'W', 'W', 'W'};` or another way of writing that `char arr[] = {57, 57, 57, 57};`

Comment: The reason a char type is used, it that it only takes 8bits.  My next option is 16bits.  Space is extremely limited in a microcontroller.  Since I am passing non-Unicode character information (ASCII) 8bits is the perfect fit.  As for pushing the literal 57, ie arr[0]=57;  that is not working(when xferd to the function), hence my post in the first place.

Comment: I just think you haven't clearly explained your goal. If you are trying to pass an array of byte values to a function, I don't see anything holding you back. It can be done with or without null byte if you are in control of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function requires a string ( char[] ) as an argument.
When you pass "William" it is interpreted as a string, that's normal.
When you pass "W" it is also interpreted as a string:

```
string[2] = { 'W' + 0 } //notice the null byte following your char
```

That's because you used double-quotes " instead of single-quotes '.
Therefore passing 57 or 'W' is viewed as a single char and not a char[]/string which then gives you an error since your function is expecting a char[] and you gave it a char.